# Generators of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ under multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Define, for $p$ prime, $G_p = \{a \in \mathbb{Z}_p | a^{p-1}=1, \mathbb{Z}_p = \{0,1,a,...,a^{p-2}\}\}$

This is one of the problems:

> Find the order of $G_{17}$

My issue is that I'm not quite sure how to think of $G_p$.  I tried associating it with $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^\times$, but I'm struggling to think of any way to do so. If I could do this, I'd be able to say that $|G_p| = p-1$ as my intuition tells me especially given that $|\mathbb{Z}_p^\times| = p-1 \iff p$ prime.

I also tried proving that if $\operatorname{gcd}(a,p)=1$, $a \in G_p$. However, I can't seem to wrap my mind around $a$: as far as my understanding goes, it generates $\mathbb{Z}_p$ but under multiplication ($\operatorname{mod} p$) rather than addition, so I'm a bit uncertain about how to work with it.

We've already seen that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field, and that $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ is cyclic

Comment: From what you write, you know that $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ is a cyclic group of order $p-1$. That is, $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times\cong \mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$, where the operation on the right hand side is addition. So now the question is: how many elements $x\in \mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$ have the property that $\langle x\rangle = \mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$?

Comment: @froggie Thanks, I think I see how to proceed from there.  The problem would be difficult for arbitrary $p$ but we have given $p$ in the problem, of course.
$x \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ is a generator if $\operatorname{gcd}(x,n) = 1$, correct? Or was it $x$ does not divide $n$?

Comment: Glad I could help. It's true that $x\in \mathbb{Z}_n$ is a generator if and only if $(x,n) = 1$. The number of such $x$ is typically denoted $\varphi(n)$. The function $\varphi$ is called *Euler's totient function*, and it turns out not to be that hard to compute. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function).